# Can low-cost purchases be accepted safely with no confirmations?

Tags: doublespend, zero-confirmation

From reading online, the general sentiment to this seems to be "no". You need at least 1 confirmation to prevent a double spend attack.

But in [Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/6ebc56febd0ef4dbf93edfb261fb28c3a8579fc7/ch02.asciidoc#bobs-view), there's this note:

> A common misconception about bitcoin transactions is that they must be 
>   "confirmed" by waiting 10 minutes for a new block, or up to 60 minutes
>   for a full six confirmations. Although confirmations ensure the
>   transaction has been accepted by the whole network, such a delay is
>   unnecessary for small-value items such as a cup of coffee. A merchant
>   may accept a valid small-value transaction with no confirmations, with
>   no more risk than a credit card payment made without an ID or a
>   signature, as merchants routinely accept today.

Is this correct? I'm running an e-commerce platform where sellers typically set item prices in the range $1-$5 and I'm debating whether to allow zero-confirmation payments.

I can understand the rationale for a cup of coffee but with virtual items online, an attacker could try to double spend on many cheap items simultaneously.